# Cloudfront url not playing video(.m3u8) in browser instead downloads the file and also gives playback error in JW Player?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

The error which i received while I try to play that video in JWT player

```
This video file cannot be played.(Error Code: 232011)
```

Testing url is:

```
https://d3k6mid18sl9go.cloudfront.net/media/HLS/107381_0dbaa5a3-16ab-4e1e-bf9e-565df5b380b3-1589866929112/107381_0dbaa5a3-16ab-4e1e-bf9e-565df5b380b3-master-playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: You might want to compare the headers between a request hosted in cloudfront and one without.

Comment: I have two cloudfront distributions with same settings out of which one url runs perfectly fine in JW player but other do not.

Comment: When we open the same link (given in the description) in mobile browser it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @ChetanVashisth Hi bro, Let us know how you solved this issue?

Comment: Haven't found anything yet @Abhijith